# Tracking downloads with NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsoperationqueue

I have a queue with 5 `NSOperations`. The queue has its `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount` set to 1. Each operation is basically a call to the server to download particular file.

What would be the best way to track if the download of one file has finished to start another `NSOperation` *only* when the file is saved to disk? Or is there a way to make `NSOperations` aware of the file's download progress?

Comment: i am not sure..but you can use nested dispatch queue for this purpose.it will be easy and less lines code

Comment: @iVishal as far as I'm concerned, NSOperationQueue is built on top of GCD, so it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply subclass `NSOperation` and put your code for downloading and saving data to filesystem into the `-main` method of your `NSOperation` subclass And after your operation is done, the next operation in `NSOperationQueue` will start executing automatically

```
@implementation MyOperation

- (void) main {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        NSLog(@"** operation cancelled **");
    } else {
        NSURL *conUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *conData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: conUrl options: NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error: & error];
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [
                [UIImage alloc] initWithData: conData];

            NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex: 0];
            NSString *jpgFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@.jpg", cacheDir, textLabel];
            conData = [NSData dataWithData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
            [conData writeToFile: jpgFilePath atomically: YES];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Operation finished");
}


@end
```

Comment: How exactly should I start the next NSOperation? On what value should I check in my NSOperationQueue cycle?

Comment: You can add all your operations to NSOperationQueue at once by calling -addOperation methods, they will be handled automatically. Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

You should override `isFinished` method in your `NSOperation` subclass to return `YES` only when it is actually finished.